# Is 'namespace export ' necessary in TCL?

Tags: namespaces, tcl

Is 'namespace export ... ' necessary, in order to use the variable/procs of that namespace in a different namespace using the 'namespace import *' command.
Should we really do the 'export' in the source namespace and 'import'in the destination namespace.

Answer (score 2):

All `namespace export` does is make commands available for `namespace import` and prompts them to appear in a simple-mode `namespace ensemble` (though you've got other options for that). If you don't want to support `namespace import`, you don't have to; just never export anything.

You invoke commands in another namespace using the fully-qualified syntax:

```
::the::other::namespace::command "some argument, as normal"
```

You can also use partial namespace names; that's pretty common as a leading `::` is a bit ugly...

Comment: If a given TCL file which exports that namespace also provides itself as a package.... how to use it? Using 'namespace import'? or 'package require'... can I simply import the namespace without using package require? or are these tasks independent?

Comment: @chidambar They're independent tasks. The `package require` makes the code available at all, doing such `source` and `load` calls as are necessary behind the scenes. The documented commands might also be `namespace export`ed but it is entirely up to you to choose how to actually use the package. FWIW, I usually do _not_ use `namespace import` since I prefer to use the qualified names (I think that's a bit clearer when I come to maintain the code, but that's entirely up to you).

Answer (score 0):

In general, I don't want to do namespace import/export: I want the variables/procs to stay where they are. Importing might pollute the destination namespace, which is against the namespace's design.